# CFMutableDataRef Released But Still Causing a Memory Leak

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I have the following code in a class method:

```
CFMutableDataRef pixelData = CFDataCreateMutableCopy(0, 0,
CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage)));

UInt8 const *data = (UInt8 *)CFDataGetMutableBytePtr(pixelData);
int pixelInfo = ((image.size.width * scale * point.y) + point.x ) * 4;
UInt8 alpha = data[pixelInfo + 3];
CFRelease(pixelData);
```

When I do the analysis with XCode, it shows a "Potential leak of an object" at the end of this method. Since I have released the pixelData, I have no clue where the leak could be. When I use instrumentation, I get a leak caused by CGDataProviderCopyData. As I have read elsewhere, the problem should be solved by calling CFRelease(pixelData); 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a double-copy. You shouldn't be calling `CFDataCreateMutableCopy()` here. `CGDataProviderCopyData()` already does the copy for you (as it says in its name).

Comment: I see, thank you. The reason I have used the copy is because of bad access that I used tp get, which is apparently a common problem on iOS 6. To solve the problem it was recommended to use the mutable copy. Thx, anyways :)

Comment: It's true, you will need to create a mutable copy in order to call `CFDataGetMutableBytePtr()`, though in this code, you could use `CFDataGetBytePtr()` on the `CFData` and not create a `CFMutableData`. If you really do need a mutable copy, then you will need to keep a pointer to the result of `CGDataProviderCopyData()` so you can release it after making a mutable copy (and then later releasing the mutable copy as well).

Answer (score 3):

As you are not storing a reference to the data returned by CGDataProviderCopyData, you are not able to send it a release message later.

As Rob points out, your 2nd copy is not necessary.

This should work and avoid the leak:

```
CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
UInt8 const* data = (UInt8*)CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);
```